# How can I prevent tmux from blocking when I scroll up?

Tags: tmux

tmux is awesome, but I'm often in situations where scrolling up causes (admittedly minor but still undesirable) problems.  For instance, I have a node.js server running in one window, and BrowserSync trying to reload the app whenever I change files.  If I've scrolled up to read some `console.log` output (but forget that I'm blocking the server), and then I make a change in my editor, nothing happens.

Is there a way to get tmux not to block the server, but simply stop add new output to the bottom of the scroll buffer, and let me keep seeing the same section of the buffer that I had previously scrolled to?

Comment: Is copy mode not what you are looking for @iconoclast ?

Comment: Did you find a solution? Just ran into this.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently [an acknowledged tmux issue](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/431) for some programs which was worked around in version 2.3.

Comment: Describing the workaround would make this a better answer...

Comment: The workaround is described in the linked issue report, but it is nothing a user can do (other than upgrading to the improved tmux version). I guess it would be more correct to state the issue was mitigated.

Comment: Supposedly this was fixed in version 2.3. However, I still have the same problem in 2.6...

Answer (score 1):

Start your applications as background jobs `$cmd &`

- Output will still jump onto the current session
- Anything you do on the cli won't block the process
- Get any background job status with `jobs -l`
- Kill any jobs with `kill $jobnumber`